# Typeahead bloodhound prefetch results in internal server error (ASP.NET)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, typeahead

I want to dynamically add typeahead to my textboxes in a ASP.NET solution. In my project I have a service, so far a Test-method which should return a list of suggestions from my server.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public string[] Test()
{
    var test =  new[] {"Test1", "Test2"};
    return test;
}
```

I try to call my web method using this javascript code

```
function addTypeahead(textbox) {
    var bloodHound = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: function (d) {
            return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value.toString());
        },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        prefetch: {
            url: "http://localhost:23135/Service/SomeService.asmx/Test",
            filter: function (items) {
                return $.map(items, function (item) {
                    return { value: item.value.toString() }
                });
            },
            ttl: 1000
        },
        storage: textbox

    });
    bloodHound.initialize();

    $(textbox).typeahead({ highlight: true }, {
        hint: false,
        name: textbox,
        source: bloodHound.ttAdapter()
    });
}
```

but all I get is a Internal Server Error (500) when trying to retrieve my suggestions. But if I make an ajax call instead I don't get an internal server error. The following code works perfectly fine.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:23135/Service/SomeService.asmx/Test",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus) {
        alert(textStatus);
    },
    success: function (suggestions) {
        console.log("suggestions:", suggestions);
    }
});
```

Any reason to why the first javacode snippet doesn't work?

Comment: Debugged what it sends to server differently?

Comment: Can you post the complete response of the ajax call including headers?

Comment: Also the description of the 500 server error would be most helpfull. You can probybly inspect the response in chrome's network tab of dev tools

Comment: Of course. This is the response. http://pastebin.com/ri5w8XFZ

Comment: It seems like the difference between the two calls is that in the $.ajax-call the content-type is application/json; charset=utf-8 whilst in the bloodhound-call the content-type is text/plain; charset=utf-8. However, I don't know how to change this.